# Pulling PDFs out of a specific directory with numerous sub folders

Tags: python, pdf

I am very new to Python and thought this would be a simple project to start with. I have 1200 or so PDFs that were transferred to me, each in their own individual subfolder with one PDF file in each folder. I am attempting to move all the PDFs into a single folder.

What I have attempted so far:

```
import os
import shutil

source_folder = os.path.abspath(r'\Reference Documents\')

destination_folder= os.path.abspath(r'\Reference Files')

for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(source_folder):
    for file in files:
        path_file=os.path.join(folder, file)
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            shutil.copy2(os.path.join(source_folder, file), destination_folder)
```

This gives me an error saying `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Reference Documents\\AD053.pdf'.`

AD053 is the first file it should be copying. If I change the above code to have the source folder be `r'\Reference Documents\AD'`, which is the folder the file is in, the copy is successful.

So essentially, what I have written does not search the subfolders in the Reference Documents for any PDFs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `shutil.copy2(path_file, destination_folder)`

Comment: @erich The removal of "\" is not correct as that's a literal "\" inside of a raw string

Comment: Then you have to escape it twice like `'\\'`

Comment: @Erich that's only the case in a regular string, not a raw string. Note the "r" before the quotes

Comment: @jordanm i did not notice, thanks. the python syntax highlighting tricked me there

Comment: @Erich yeah, the markdown didn't handle it well

Comment: @jordanm thank you very much, that fixed it for me. Was the issued that I was referencing the wrong variable or the second os.path.join statement? Again, extremely new to Python so thanks.